# how to define stcat,strlen,substr in sasm

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am using Sasm Ide.I want to know that how to define strcat,substr,strlen macro in sasm

```
   %include "io.inc"
    %define String "abc"
    %strcat "Alpha: ", '12" screen'
    %strcat beta '"foo"\', "'bar'"

    section .text
    global CMAIN
    CMAIN:
    PRINT_STRING String

        ;write your code here
        xor eax, eax
        ret
```

Comment: You haven't specified what you want those macros to do. Do you want them to expand to compile-time operations or to run-time operations? Also, what specific problem did you run into when trying to implement these macros? Just asking _"I need X. How do I write it?"_ isn't a particularly good question for StackOverflow.

Comment: i want to define macros and after that used that macros in code area to find out substring,length of string  and concatenate two string

Comment: I have define string macro above as "abc" how can i find the length of this string and substring.

Comment: http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.05/html/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.2.2

Comment: I can't understand... please give some code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%include "io.inc"
%defstr myname ABC
%strlen length myname
%substr text "This is String" 3,2 
%strcat names 'Assembly' , '.Language'


section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
PRINT_STRING myname
NEWLINE
PRINT_DEC 2,length
NEWLINE
PRINT_STRING text
NEWLINE
PRINT_STRING names 

    ;write your code here
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```